Ambient Occlusion not spreading outside specific area
Please excuse me if this is just not how AO works and I'm looking for something else but I want to know how to get my AO to actually cover this area for the wall material (The completely white material)

If I move the object intersecting with the wall back a little bit, you can clearly see that the AO is working but it never goes outside that area

I want to make the AO go beyond the exact point where it intersects with the object in order to make some edge imperfection with its material.
These are my Fast GI settings. Messing with them changed almost nothing

This is my node setup for the wall. Nothing much changed when I increased the distance.

